# Powershell -replace not replacing content

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to replace a line in a text file. Here is my text file and `Powershell` script

**Text File**

```
String^ m5 = ss.FileMD5(a, salt);
    if (m5 != "e11621cc4370a5203423cc1d1ee8c2a7") {
        return 6;       //mismatch
    }
```

**Powershell Script**

```
$fl = "G:\tmp\test\test.txt"
$find = "m5 !="
$repl = 'if (m5 != "aaaaaaaa") {'
$content = (Get-Content $fl)

$line = $content | Select-String $find | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
if ($line -eq $null) {
  "Match Not Found"
  exit
} else {
  $content = $content | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $line, $repl }
  $content  # print replaced content
}
```

It is always printing old content without replacement.

What the wrong i am doing in this script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trying the replace your $line variable `if (m5 != "e11621cc4370a5203423cc1d1ee8c2a7") {` contains special regex characters that need to be escaped.

Change

```
$content = $content | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $line, $repl }
```

to

```
$content = $content | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($line), $repl }
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `$content = ($content).replace($line,$repl)` which treats it as plain text and not regex. `String.replace()` is a method where `-replace` is an operator

Comment: @Drew `($content).replace($line,$repl)` also working fine. I will remember it.